# Why does final class WebView contain protected method getChildren() in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, final

[`WebView` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) is final. It contains method `getChildren()`, which is protected.

How to use it then?

**UPDATE**

The question is not about `protected` adn/or `final` keywords, but about why this is done this way? What is the reason to have protected members in final classes?

Comment: `protected` field can be still accessed by other classes in the same package

Comment: check the edit of my answer

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi That's not exactly correct.  Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/2498729

Comment: @Suzan Cioc - please see my updated answer on why it's protected.

Answer (score 1):

protected means "package and inheritance access" so classes in the same package can access this method.

EDIT:

answer to your edit: it's because designers of this class wanted this method to be available ONLY to classes within the same package and no other classes (thus you cannot extend it because their made it final)

Comment: Actually, you could still argue that it makes more sense to use the default visibility (no modifier). That explicitly means "only classes in this package" and is identical to protected if no subclasses can exist.

Answer (score 0):

When it declared as protected, Still the classes who instantiate the `WebView` class in the same package can use that method.

You might think that it cannot be extended as it is `final`, there is no way to access it outside of the class. Yes, that is true but with in the package, they can.

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------
protected   Y      **Y**        Y           N
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, final classes cannot be extended. A final class can not be subclassed.

**protected Modifier** - Accessed by other classes in the:

- same package
- any subclasses of the class in which they are referred (i.e. **same package** or **different package**).

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend it because it's final.

- Create and instance of Webview class and call `newWebViewInstance.getChildren()`.
- You can create a package with the same package of Webview, but anybody with right sense of Java programming language wouldn't do it.

**Update**

I don't like to make member/methods of a final class protected . IMHO  that is bad programming practise unless in this case.

**Why was it made protected?**

```
WebView extends javafx.scene.Parent
```

And `getAllChildren()` is an method of `javafx.scene.Parent` which is  of protected scope.

```
protected javafx.collections.ObservableList<javafx.scene.Node> getChildren()
```

As we now know Webview is a subclass of `javafx.scene.Parent` and overrides `getChildren()`. If it changes the scope (default being stricter than protected) it breaks the overriding contract.

Hope it's clear now.